# Prevent texture deformation when mesh deforms

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a plane, which has a texture UV mapped to it.  Let's say this plane is square and the texture is square.

I am trying to make a mouth (basically an opening in the plane which will have teeth, tongue, etc. that goes "down into" the plane) in this plane, but *not* deform the image on the plane.  Now this mouth will change shape, particularly when speaking (which I will do using shapekeys), and I don't know how to prevent the texture from getting deformed when the mouth is getting deformed due to speaking.

Now, I have found a modifier called UV Project, however, that does not work in Cycles, which is what I'm using.

So the main question is: How can I prevent a texture from deforming due to the mesh moving?

**Edit**  Added a .blend file, it should have the texture packed into it (a 1000x1000 pixel png).  I have made some vertex groups on the "Face" object, with the teeth.  Shapekeys and inside mouth color not finalized yet, so they are not in this .blend.

[image]

Comment: UV Project works in Cycles just fine.

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh From what I was reading [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html) all the way at the bottom of the page, it says "this option is not yet available for Cycles".  Am I reading that wrong?

Comment: The "not available in cycles" is only referring to the last option - the uv project material option related to perspective cameras. The rest works in cycles.

Comment: I don't think you want UV Project anyways, because when the mesh is deformed the texture will appear to slide over the mesh. The texture will deform, I think you just need to set up the geometry of the mesh to minimized a lot of stretching. Can you post a screen shot or your blend file?

Comment: @sambler Ah, I had not realized that, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh  Added a blend file, it should have the texture packed into it.  Hope it clarifies my situation.

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh  I tried a number of things with the mesh following your advice, and everything appears to be working now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took Todd McIntosh's advice on messing with the mesh to try to prevent it from deforming, and I have (IMO) good results:

[image: Left and right side of mouth closed]

This image has the top and bottom of the mouth not closed at all, but the sides "fully" (only partially due to how my texture will work) closed using shapekeys.

Basically `loop cut and slide` a ring around the edge, then from the loop `extrude` and `scale` in.  Make sure to only scale in on the X and Y axes, or whatever two axes you want to prevent the surface from bowing in.

I have the shapekeys set up so that the sides of the mouth can't come more than halfway to the center, but the top and bottom can go all the way.  There is a little bit of intersection if you have the top mostly closed, and the sides all the way in, but for my purposes, I can work around that.

And here is a blend file with some shapekeys and vertex groups if you want to test.

[image]